# URL file under windows 10 shows wrong icon

Tags: windows, url, shortcut

I've made the next URL file using text editor:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://192.168.33.7/
IconFile=http://192.168.33.7/SomeICOFile.ico
HotKey=0
IconIndex=0
IDList=
```

and saved it on the desktop.
under windows XP The shortcut icon is the file saved on the server - SomeICOFile.ico

under windows 7 and 10 it gets the default browser icon as icon.  (Yet, it leads to the right page).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It seems that the name of the .url file must be same like the name of the .ico file in Win10